# How do I find a line that starts with a letter in Bash? Neither grep nor awk would work

Tags: bash, awk, grep, etl

I have been trying to find lines starting with an E which also have a capital A after a space with this

```
grep 'E* A' file.txt | grep '^E'
```

The first part of the code will work (printing all lines which have an A after a space, although I don't really understand how, as it doesn't work without the 'E'), but the second one isn't. I know it's rather easy to do this with sql, but I'm convinced that there's a ay to do it with pure bash as well.

Comment: Why not `grep '^E A' file.txt`?

Comment: Probably you don't realize that `E*` will find lines which do not contain E (the star says "zero or more of the preceding"). Find a line which actually contains an initial E and your script should work, although of course as pointed out by @WiktorStribiżew it's much better to use a single regex.

Comment: Well, the question can also be understood as *match lines starting with `E` and then having space+A` somewhere to the right*, then `'^E.* A'` should work. What is your `grep` version, BTW?

Comment: Provide the missing [mcve]. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didn't work, it was my first choice btw. It's  3.1

Comment: Yeah, nothing will work since there are no concrete requirements. It is unclear what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` does not have a logical AND operator, unless using pipes as:

```
grep ' A' file.txt | grep '^E'
```

In this particular case, you could set up a BRE as

```
grep '^E.* A' file.txt
```

or you might want to use awk for such operations

```
awk '/^E/ && / A/' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the dot!

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you might also be interested in

```
grep '^E.*\sA' file.txt
```

which matches lines starting with E (^E) then any character (.) zero or more times (*) and then one space (\s) with a A after it.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Comment: `\s` is a PCRE extension which is not traditionally supported by `grep`